# regular expression-javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to get the string which comes between first`:`and first `.`

```
s:4332Hhj4j32hh432kjh.EF4324rf46543DSVC3443
```

I tried the following:

```
/:(.*?)\./g
```

But still it catches : and .

How can I exclude them?

Here is my example: http://www.regexr.com/3busf

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `matches[1]` instead of `matches[0]`:

```js
var re = /:(.*?)\./g; 
var str = 's:4332Hhj4j32hh432kjh.EF4324rf46543DSVC3443';
var matches;
 
while ((matches = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (matches.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }

    console.log(matches[0]); // ":4332Hhj4j32hh432kjh."
    console.log(matches[1]); // "4332Hhj4j32hh432kjh"
}
```

Comment: ummm how come regexr.com was returning `:` and `.` as well? Ok Thanks

Comment: It is the whole match. You want to capture the submatch `(.*?)` which is at index 1.

Comment: I see Thanks  :-) I need to wait to accept your answer; it does not let me now